# Script to add pre-made ppt to new ppt

Tags: vba, shell, powershell, powerpoint

I have several ppt files, and I am wanting to create a script that asks which of these pre-made ppt files I would like to use to create a NEW presentation. 
example -
I have ppt1, ppt2, ppt3 and ppt4.
A script opens asking "Select the ppt files you want to add to your new presentation" and then a list of these files is shown. I put a checkmark by the ones I want (let's say ppt2 and ppt4) and when I click OK it takes these files and copies or adds them to a new ppt and asks what I want to name the new presentation. That's all. I would think this would be easy, but I am new and looking for assistance. I have searched and tested several different scripting for powerpoint suggestions but nothing seems to be what I am looking for, or does not work. Even a simple starting point and I can take it from there (or at least I hope) LOL
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is way too broad. We don't write scripts for others, we help fix specific problems. You won't find an answer that fits perfectly to your needs so you need to take one step at a time. If you get stuck on a specific problem you're welcome to submit a question and we will try to help you fix it. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably not find a solution that is exactly what you want, so I suggest you draw up a "plan" for how to achieve what you want and research one step at a time. Ex.

1. Get available templates and select which to use
2. Ask user for new ppt name
3. Create new ppt
4. Read template(s) and copy slides to new ppt
5. Save new ppt

Step 1 & 2:

```
#DEMO: Create sample files
New-Item -Name "PowerPoint Templates" -ItemType Directory
New-Item -Name "ppt1.ppt" -Path '.\PowerPoint Templates' -ItemType File
New-Item -Name "ppt2.ppt" -Path '.\PowerPoint Templates' -ItemType File
New-Item -Name "ppt3.ppt" -Path '.\PowerPoint Templates' -ItemType File
New-Item -Name "ppt4.ppt" -Path '.\PowerPoint Templates' -ItemType File

#1. Get available templates and select which to use
$SelectedTemplates = Get-ChildItem -Path '.\PowerPoint Templates' |
Select-Object Name, FullName |
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title "Select the ppt files you want to add to your new presentation"

#2. Ask user for new ppt name
$OutputFileName = Read-Host "Name of new PowerPoint presentation"
```

Comment: Frode F. - Thanks - That gave me a starting point which is what I needed and am working on that.